# Папка с файлами компиляции в Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Не могу собрать проект, возникает такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде все настроил правильно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**В чем может быть дело ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выставьте на закладке `Paths` пути для компиляции `.class` файлов.